# Kindle App for Win 10 PC's

Tags: kindle-app, windows

Since Amazon has discontinued the windows kindle App and instead replaced it with their cloud offering - which sucks to say the least.
Anyone know where I may be able to download a kindle app for my Win10 PC.
thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 2):

[Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) is an excellent free application to store and to transfer books amongst *many* different devices, [including Kindle](https://www.howtogeek.com/539829/how-to-transfer-any-ebook-to-kindle-using-calibre/). There are [limitations with DRM](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/drm.html), though. There are [plug-ins to remove DRM](https://deadendroad.co/2018/11/05/how-to-remove-drm-convert-ebook/), though I do not know anything about their legality, and I avoid buying DRM-protected media on principle.